# Store data in mysql from recyclerview with button using volley

Tags: android, mysql, android-recyclerview

I am working on app that fetches data using volley and displays in feed using recyclerview.i have a button in each card that when clicked, will count the number of clicks and display it in a textview in that particular card(like instagram like button). Now i want the value of clicks to also be stored in a mysql database when the button is clicked. can anyone PLEASE help me with how i can go about this?THis is my code

CARD ADAPTER

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 11/9/2015.
 */
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    //Imageloader to load image
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    //List to store all superheroes
    List<SuperHero> superHeroes;

    //Constructor of this class
    public CardAdapter(List<SuperHero> superHeroes, Context context) {
        super();
        //Getting all superheroes
        this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.superheroes_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( final ViewHolder holder,    final int position) {
        //Getting the particular item from the list
          final SuperHero superHero = superHeroes.get(position);

        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        //Showing data on the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(superHero.getName());
        holder.textViewPublisher.setText(superHero.getPublisher());
        holder.textViewLikes.setText(superHero.getLikes());



        holder.custom_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int count;


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                count = 0;

                superHeroes.get(position).setCount(superHeroes.get(position).getCount() + 1);
                holder.txtCount.setText(superHeroes.get(position).getCount() + "");


            }

        });



    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return superHeroes.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewPublisher;
        public TextView textViewLikes;
        public TextView txtCount;
        public ImageButton custom_button;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
            textViewLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewlikes);
            txtCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
            custom_button = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.custom_button);
        }
    }
}
```

MAINACTIVITY

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener {



    //Creating a List of superheroes
    private List<SuperHero> listSuperHeroes;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    //Volley Request Queue
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    //The request counter to send ?page=1, ?page=2  requests
    private int requestCount = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Initializing Views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        //Initializing our superheroes list
        listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Calling method to get data to fetch data
        getData();

        //Adding an scroll change listener to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);

        //initializing our adapter
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, this);

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


    //Request to get json from server we are passing an integer here
    //This integer will used to specify the page number for the request ?page = requestcount
    //This method would return a JsonArrayRequest that will be added to the request queue

    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
        //Initializing ProgressBar
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        //Displaying Progressbar
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        //JsonArrayRequest of volley
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                        parseData(response);
                        //Hiding the progressbar
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        //Returning the request
        return jsonArrayRequest;
    }



    //This method will get data from the web api
    private void getData() {
        //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
        //Incrementing the request counter
        requestCount++;
    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            //Creating the superhero object
            SuperHero superHero = new SuperHero();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                //Getting json
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding data to the superhero object
                superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                superHero.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
                superHero.setPublisher(json.getString(Config.TAG_PUBLISHER));
                superHero.setLikes(json.getString(Config.TAG_LIKES));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Adding the superhero object to the list
            listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
        }

        //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }




    //This method would check that the recyclerview scroll has reached the bottom or not
    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Overriden method to detect scrolling
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        //Ifscrolled at last then
        if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {

            //Calling the method getdata again
            getData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you setup a sqlite database? its really easy just google it

Comment: Just call the function that you use to store data in the database inside the `onClick` of your button inside the adapter, passing the ***count*** value.

Comment: yh i already have a database @Shreyans

Answer (score 1):

I will assume a scenario that would help you understand what can be done here.

Lets say `RecyclerView` has number of items and each item represents a record in `MySQL database` for the Table `Card` (another assumed name to represent from where the records are being read).

this `Card Table` should have a `column` called `likes` as `Integer` or `Long` to keep track of number of users liked that particular record.

Whenever a user likes a card by clicking on the button, Set the value of that card instance variable `isLiked` to true and make a network call to the API stating to increment the `likes` column count in the Card Table in the `MySQL Database`,

There can be many ways to achieve this, as implementations changes, you would have to adapt to your requirement.

```
class Card{
    public long id;
    public boolean isLiked;
    public long numberOfLikes;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isLiked() {
        return isLiked;
    }

    public void setLiked(boolean liked) {
        isLiked = liked;
    }

    public long getNumberOfLikes() {
        return numberOfLikes;
    }

    public void setNumberOfLikes(long numberOfLikes) {
        this.numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes;
    }
}
```

Comment: should i do all of these inside the onclick? @Pankaj Nimgade

Comment: yes you can make a Network call to API which will increment the likes count in OnClick()

Comment: how can i assign the value from a each 'txtCount' (textView that displays number of likes in each card) to a  string variable? @Pankay Nimgade

Comment: as each record will save number of likes to that record you can pass that value from the mysql database to client through web APIs and have another instance variable to Card class which would collect the value for numberOfLikes, than you can read that and setText() to the TextView, check the answer

Comment: @PfilMintz, this way of code has a defect in it. if you don't tack which users liked the card it would be hard to distinguish between different user when next time the RecyclerView load from the APIs

Comment: Thank you very much. Please which is the best way? Setting the value of that card instance variable isLiked to true and making a network call to the API stating to increment the likes column count in the Card Table in the MySQL Database, or storing the number of likes in a variable and then posting the value in that variable to the database. (i am trying to build a like button for a social network app) @Pankaj Nimgade

Comment: first option is better than the second one @PfilMintz, still the best option would be if you could save which users liked that card and save it in MySQL database.

Comment: ohk! that sounds better. Do u know of any tutorials or resouurces i can probably go through to help me get a fare idea of how to do this? @PankajNimgade